# MongoDB) I am curious about how to filter fields with strange names in object-type fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

if there is a DB value in the form of the following, I want to filter and migrate the corresponding value. But I don't know how.

The value has the form:

`metadata: { // ...some property "metadata.isUpdateData": true, }`

I want to delete "metadata.isUpdateData" here and just put in "isUpdateData" value.
Is there a way to filter that value??

If only "metadata.isUpdateData" exists in metadata,
It was possible to look up with

`Model.find({metadata: {"metadata.isUpdateData": true}})`

However, if there are multiple values ​​in metadata, it is not searched.

Comment: If searching is the problem, you can use: `Model.find({"metadata.metadata.isUpdateData": true}})`